# Better way to do this foreach in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

Is there a better way to get the same result that this produces?

```
foreach($data['report']->result_array() as $k){
    $array[] = $k['id'];
}
```

*Better:* in this context, meaning shorter, easier to read, or better syntax overall.

I'm a noob, so comments/suggestions/general wisdom from the programming community is welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't think of a better way to achieve this.

Of course, if you are able to alter the result_array() function you can introduce a new parameter to return the *id* field only.
However, in my opinion this decreases the readability of the code.

If you only want to load the id's from $data['report'], i would suggest defining a new specialized method that returns all the *id*'s.

Comment: May I pry?  When desiring a specific array of an object, is a foreach the best method?

Comment: Yes, definitely.
Elaboration: it's easily readable by the developer, and in most cases it is performing excellent.

Comment: I won't `-1`, but I don't like the idea of a dedicated `getIdArray` method.  To me, it just smells of bloat since why not add methods for every permutation of arrays and calculations to that one class.  Why not instead create a helper utility class that works with arrays to solve this problem generically.  That way you can reuse the solution directly without copying and pasting...  IMHO that's the better way (but again, it's just an opinion)

Comment: @rtuin: That's quite fair.  And that's why I didn't -1, it's a valid approach to the problem (and without knowing more, it could be a correct one).  I was just pointing out one possible reason to avoid that...

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to extract the 'id' field from the array of data returned by the result_array function on each element of the $data['report'] and put it into a new array, then this is probably about as efficient as you can get.

Is there something about this you find troubling? It looks fine to me (although I'd never name an array variable "$array" - something like $idArray seems more apt) if that's the objects/data structure you have to deal with. That said, I presume it's appropriately commented, etc.

Comment: Well, I'm a total php noob teaching myself...so I don't fully understand how parameters work, methods, objects etc...

Comment: I tried the `result_array()` method, but that didn't work...I'm just trying to get the id array out of the 'report' array, that's all...

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = array_map(function($k) { 
    return $k['id'];
}, $data['report']->result_array());
```

You are limited to doing just that single thing within the "loop," so I don't know if it qualifies as "better." It's just different.

Some people prefer the map/reduce style of programming, but it's not very common in PHP code, as the syntax isn't that good and anonymous functions were only recently introduced.

Edit: Removed the bit about speed comparison.

Comment: I didn't downvote but this is definitely not faster, nor shorter, nor easier to read, etc :)

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel, haha. I tested, and `array_map` is definitely slower for this trivial of a loop. @webbiedave, given PHP's syntax, I agree.

Comment: it isn't faster nor slower. it's just equal. for the small amounts of data processed in the 99.999% of our scripts it's totally negligible. And if you happen to process large amount of data, you have to find a place to optimize far before you reach this ugly loop

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel, I agree completely with the idea that this isn't the type of optimizations you should ever concern yourself with. Just by using PHP, you've made the decision that speed isn't a deciding factor. But on the topic of readability, some people actually prefer map/reduce/filter techniques. Although, I doubt many of them use PHP, given its ugly syntax for it.

Comment: In fact, PHP is pretty fast. Most of Alexa's top100 sites are built with php. And speed is very important for them. But the speed of the code itself is least important thing. It's well optimized and never being a bottleneck. But the speed of data manipulations is the subject of optimization.

Comment: I don't think he was saying PHP isn't fast as far as interpreted languages are concerned but, rather, as compared to all programming languages, i.e., if you're writing a command-line program and you choose PHP instead of C, then speed is not your priority.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one better way (at least what I would determine to be better):

```
$reportIds = array();
$dataArray = $data['report']->result_array();

foreach($dataArray as $reportElement) {
    $reportIds[] = $reportElement['id'];
}
```

It uses more meaningful variable names (as I'm guessing), and is a little bit more verbose about what's going on.  Remember, readability trumps all other concerns with the exception of correctness.

Of course, depending on the needs of what you're doing, you could also write a method to fetch only the ids (along side `result_array()`) or an iterator to do this for you:

```
class MultiDimensionalArrayIterator extends ArrayIterator {
    protected $key = '';

    public function __construct(array $array, $key) {
        $this->key = $key;
        parent::__construct($array);
    }

    public function current() {
        $data = parent::current();
        return $data[$this->key];
    }

    public function offsetGet($index) {
        $data = parent::offsetGet($index);
        return $data[$this->key];
    }

    // Implement other overrides to consistently handle iteration
}
```

Usage:

```
$dataArray = $data['report']->result_array();
$iterator = new MultiDimensionalArrayIterator($dataArray, 'id');
$reportIds = iterator_to_array($iterator);
```

There are lots of possibilities.  The question comes in what do you need, and what does the rest of your project need...